# Como confirmar borrado de fila

Tags: web

Me gustaria preguntar si quieren o no eliminar un Paciente mediante un SI o NO algo sencillo...
Lo he intentado y me pide si quiere borrarlo mediante Javascript, pero, no hace nada...

```
<a href='pagines/esborrar.asp?id=<%=rs("Numero")%>&que=<%=nomfitxer%>'><img src="images/delete.gif" border="0" alt="Borrar" /></a>
```

Esto es lo que he probado:

Script

```js
function irAWeb() {

  if (confirm("¿Quieres ir a la página del Mensajeitor?")) {

    document.location.href = 'pagines/esborrar.asp?id=<%=rs("Numero")%>&que=<%=nomfitxer%>';
  }
}
```

```html
<a onclick="irAWeb(); return false;" href='pagines/esborrar.asp?id=<%=rs("Numero")%>&que=<%=nomfitxer%>'><img src="images/delete.gif" border="0" alt="Borrar" /></a>
```

Comment: El `confirm` lo está haciendo.. el problema está en la pagina a la que mandas la solicitud. Has hecho algun log?  Necesitamos mas informacion

Comment: @lois6b tiene razón.. tu ejemplo tal y como está funciona (aunque tengas el `return false` el `document.location.href` debería funcionar, aunque por mejorar la comprensión deberías indicar el destino en un único lugar y hacerlo como te propongo. ¿El enlace funciona como esperas si no le pones el evento `onlick`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que estás cancelando el evento sí o sí con ese `return false`.

Además, si el `href` indica el destino no necesitas el `document.location.href`.

Si delegamos el valor de `return` a la llamada funcionará como deseas:

```js
function irAWeb(event) {
  if (confirm("¿Quieres ir a la página del Mensajeitor?") == false) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="return irAWeb(event);" href='pagines/esborrar.asp?id=<%=rs("Numero")%>&que=<%=nomfitxer%>'> [Pulse para borrar] </a>
```

Tras dar más detalles en el chat hice una última modificación para cancelar la propagación de eventos con [`Event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) para evitar que el elemento padre (un `<tr>` con otro evento `onclick`) hiciera una acción al cancelar el borrado.

Es importante pasar el evento como parámetro a la función con `onclick="return irAWeb(event);"`.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64356/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-como-confirmar-borrado-de-fila).

Comment: Al OP, [se paso por alto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/97205/16597) copiar parte de la respuesta xD. +1 por tu aporte