# Fallo en confirm() en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una funcionalidad para que cuando se quiera borrar un Paciente al hacer clic en borrar, pregunte si realmente quiere o no borrarlo.

Muestra la pregunta, pero cuando le doy a cancelar me lo borra igualmente y si le doy a aceptar pasa igual.

El `onClick` para llamar la función de JavaScript esta dentro de un `<tr>`, ese `<tr>` principal tiene también un `onClick`, no se si eso puede causar algún conflicto.

Este es el código usado:

JS:

```
function irAWeb(event) {
  if (confirm("¿Quieres ir a la página del Mensajeitor?") == false) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="return irAWeb();" href='pagines/esborrar.asp?id=<%=rs("Numero")%>&que=<%=nomfitxer%>'> <img src="images/delete.gif" border="0" alt="Borrar" /> </a>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema se debe se te ha olvidado pasar `event` al llamar a la función `irAWeb` en el `onclick`.

### Solución:

Modifica el `HTML` de la siguiente forma:

```
<a onclick="return irAWeb(event);" href='pagines/esborrar.asp?id=<%=rs("Numero")%>&que=<%=nomfitxer%>'>
  <img src="images/delete.gif" border="0" alt="Borrar" />
</a>
```

Comment: Mira que en [la respuesta que le di](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97079/como-confirmar-borrado-de-fila#97082) estaba bien puesto. Mi +1 por ayudarle :)

Answer (score 2):

NO sabría decirte porque sucede eso, a mi igual me paso alguna ves y lo solucione agregando una linea código mas, donde obtengo el resultado del `confirm`

```js
function irAWeb(event) {
  $bool=confirm("¿Quieres ir a la página del Mensajeitor?");
  if($bool){
  alert("marcaste OK");
  }else{
  alert("marcaste Cancelar");
  }
  
}
```

```html
<a onclick="return irAWeb();" href='#'> <img src="images/delete.gif" border="0" alt="Borrar" /> </a>
```

Sé que no parece tener ningún cambio ya que tendria que ser lo mismo, pero de esta manera funciona correctamente.

Comment: Hola la solución de Marcos me funcionó perfectamente, pero gracias por aportar tu aporte! 